# Take input from user when running PHP in CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is there any way I can take input from user while running a PHP script via Command line interface?

Answer (score 0):

Waits for a return (newline):

```
$handle = fopen ('php://stdin', 'r');
$input  = fgets($handle);
```

For a single character such as a menu choice:

```
$input  = fgetc($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

just type

```php
$line = fgets(STDIN);
```

example :

```php
<?php
echo "What's your name ? ";
$line = fgets(STDIN);
echo "hi $line";
```

in your console :

```sh
php demo.php
What's your name ? Arrobe
hi Arrobe
```

fgets open a file in read mode

STDIN (for Standard Input) in a special file : your keyboard

source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: Can you add more explanation? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer